# R.java is not generating, R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am doing an application in which I didnt changed anything and still it is giving me an error on R.java file that R cannot be resolved to a variable...

I have done all the things like: project->clean

close and open the project again

close the eclipse and restart it agagin but no solution...

I am not able to fix this problem....This problem is so much irritating....Can anyone pls help me in this case??

Comment: check which R file has got included into your class if it is android.R then remove it and import your R class

Comment: check any import's in the project with com.--.R (like this) delete that and refresh. project

Comment: no,..it doesn't have any of the import on R..

Comment: @ShabbirPanjesha: no..its not android.R....I want to add my own project R.java file...But as this file is auto generated...and will generate when I am compiling my project..but due to these errors I am not able to compile

Comment: then definitely one of your xml file contains error or not well formed.

Comment: No but earlier that project was working fine...now I didn't change anything from xml file

Comment: can you post your xml files at shabbir@sphinx-solution.com ? Lets have a look over them.

Comment: Is your project contains images in drawable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably an error in one of your resource files, you need to properly check all your resources to find if any of them contain errors. The resource with an error will have an error red cross on its icon. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no other errors that might cause this error, also look at this entry:

[R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: I ahve tried all the methods mentioned here,but still didn't get anything

Comment: last time I have seen this error I have misspelled android name in  android:id in one of the widget. If your project have not changed then maybe you have made changes to filesystem? changed permissions, folder names, etc.?