# R.java Files on F-Droid.com

Tags: java, android, r.java-file, motodev-studio

I'm trying to download and analyze a few apps from F-Droid.com but when I grab all the java files and all the other files and copy them into my IDE (Motodev Studio for Android) errors pop up all over the place because the R.java file is missing. I can't seem to find the reason why the R.java file is absent and the app (obviously) won't run without it. can anyone help? Here is an example of an app I'm trying to download:

http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=arity.calculator&fdpage=2

Comment: The link I posted in the question has a link to source code. To download the files, you need to go to the source code link and use the command prompt. From there I've been finding the files on my computer and copying and pasting them into the IDE. I feel like the R.java (due to its nature of mainly being for id's) should be generated by the IDE and not copied in like the other files. But if this is the case, I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not create R.java, it will be automatically generated by system as it's content is based on the resource files (including layouts and preferences).

If you run a clean on the project it should regenerate all the generated java files. If not then may be there are some error in your layout xml

You Can follow this Links

[Magic behind R.java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048415/magic-behind-r-java-file)

[Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

[R.java is not generating, R cannot be resolved to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643873/r-java-is-not-generating-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

Comment: Do you know how to run a clean in Motodev Studio?

Comment: Write click on your project from motodev then you will find at lower part clean selected project -- click it, that will do. If then your problem is not solved please check the xml you used , may be there exists some problem for that reason it is not generating.

Comment: Thanks very much. I found the "clean" in Motodev. It's still giving me trouble though. There's some problem: "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fileName' in package 'com.leinardi.kitchentimer'" Is this due to the generated code or is this just strictly a layout problem?